# error compile angular project - latest ag-grid version 26.2.0

Tags: compiler-errors

Build at: 2021-11-17T10:26:49.029Z - Hash: 0738d0a50a569d13 - Time: 2254ms
V>' requires 2 type argument(s).
Error: node_modules/ag-grid-enterprise/dist/lib/setFilter/setFilter.d.ts:4:40 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ProvidedFilter<M,
V>' requires 2 type argument(s).

4 export declare class SetFilter extends ProvidedFilter {
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: I am only changed ag-grid source like: export declare class SetFilter extends ProvidedFilter<SetFilterModel, null> and it is working - compiled and run. But ti is only workaround solution. Seems me ag-grig have bug in this file: setFilter.d.ts